# Is it possible to authenticate MS AD users against another MS AD without a trust?

Tags: active-directory, authentication, users

I have two Microsoft active directories, lets call them External and Internal,

What I want to do is:

- Add users to Internal AD without password (Just save some other attributes for them).
- When a user tries to login, the password will be checked against the External AD.
- This is only for domain users not for the administrators.
- Both Active Directories are on Windows servers.
- I don't know what is the specific version of the External server. But I know it's a windows server.
- I am able to authenticate users using openldap on linux. "By suppling a username and password". Which means it's possible to authenticate the users.

Please note that I am not trying to steal the passwords or anything. I just want my internal AD to send the username and password to the External AD and the External will respond if they match or not.

There are multiple services in my company that uses the External password for the employees ( like Exchange mail ). I want to keep them using the same username and password everywhere.

Here is the permissions I have:

- I don't have any "Administrator" permissions on the External AD. Just a regular user permission.
- I have full permission on the Internal AD.
- I have full control over the computers and users that will try to login in the Internal AD.

some people suggested that I use cross-realm Kerberos trust along with guiding me to the right place of writing this question.
I looked up the cross-realm Kerberos trust, But I found out that I need to have a password for the trust entered on both ADs. Which I can't do since I don't have Administrator permissions on the External AD.

You help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify the "without the External administrator even knowing about it"-part of your question?

Comment: I mean, he wouldn't know that internal users that authenticate from his active directory are actually being redirected from mine.

Comment: Ok, but when those users have trouble logging in or connecting to network resources, who is responsible for troubleshooting? From the perspective of the other admin I would certainly not be too happy resolving support requests and discovering an unauthorized auth proxy setup along the way. Doesn't it just seem like a perfect recipy for trouble?

Comment: To my eyes the question, though interesting, does seem to fall under "unauthorized hacking" or "circumvention of security or policy" in http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't see why this could cause any troubles. or any security issues. I don't want to steal the passwords or sync them. I just want my internal AD to send the username and password to the External AD and the External will respond if they match or not. I am a PHP programmer and I do this all the time with ldap_bind. I don't want my employees to remember a different passwords for every service.

Comment: Ok, but then why not simply talk to the admin(s) of the external AD? That role has the key to solve this quickly and painlessly.

Comment: I talked to them but they refused for some reason. I am not an expert on AD. But it should be a very simple thing to do. just specifying an ip of the external server and using it for authentication while taking every other detail of the user from the internal AD.

Comment: I have seen such solutions and it is possible the admins simply do not understand your proposal or the technical details and are imagining risks where there are none. Or they might have a solid and perfectly understandable reason - these things tend to place requirements in the other direction too. It does come across as a business decision rather than a dev vs ops decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754361(v=ws.10).aspx) (AD LDS) sounds like a reasonable fit for what you're looking for. What you're calling the "Internal AD" can be an AD LDS instance that authenticates to what you're calling the "External AD".

I'm not sure I'm understanding your use case exactly, but I think [AD LDS bind redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794922(v=ws.10).aspx) would probably do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I never used AD LDS but I am trying to figure it out. Please give me some time for deploying and testing. Thank you for the answer Evan.

Comment: Can't we do the same with two AD DSs ?  one AD DS that authenticates to the other AD DS without making a trust relation?

Comment: There is no functionality in the AD DS product to do that. AD LDS is the only AD functionality that supports authentication outside AD (aside from trust relationships).